# How to add a git repository in xcode 9.0?

Tags: xcode, git

I'm trying to add a remote git repository in xcode project but I'm unable to find an option for that. getting option as

[image]

but expecting

[image]

Is there any other way to add remote repository to a project?

Answer (score 72):

Navigate to `Source Control` tab right next to the `Project Navigator`, then `right click` on your project and select the `Add Existing Remote`.

[image]

Then enter your remote URL.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use this command in terminal:

```
git remote add origin https://Your_git_URL.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Learning to do git from the console is very easy too [use this](https://gitexplorer.com/) as a reference

Comment: I think this is a comment and not an answer