# Xcode Dual git repos

Tags: xcode, git, github, version-control

I have an Xcode Project which currently is connected to a local git source repository so that changes can be saved

How do I add a second remote gitHub  repo.  So that Code can be stored/saved in both the local and remote?

Or How do I change the local repo to a remote GitHub repo

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To add another remote for local git repo, you can do with any of below options:

#### Option 1: Add remote in Xcode

- In Xcode -> Source Control Tab -> working copy name -> Configure the working copy -> Remote -> Add remote -> input the remote name and remote URL you want to add.
- Besides, you can also refer the post [How to add a git repository in xcode 9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892839/how-to-add-a-git-repository-in-xcode-9-0) to add remotes by clicking your project and then select Add Existing Remote option.

#### Option 2: Add remote in terminal

In the terminal window -> to the directory of the local git repo -> execute the command:

```
git remote add <remote name> <remote repo URL>
```